# jQuery text fading effect on mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to achieve a consistent text fading effect cross-browser using jQuery.

As you'll see in the example below, in the last frame or so of the animation as the text fades in, the font weight suddenly increases which makes it look jerky/clunky. 
This occurs on:

- Chrome Snow Leopard
- Safari with Snow Leopard
- FF4 pre Snow Leopard.

However, the fading looks completely smooth on

- FF4 Snow Leopard
- IE6 on windows XP
- Chrome on Windows 7

(have not tested any more). To see the effect, visit the below:

http://jsfiddle.net/jZdzK/5/

Has anyone seen this before/know of any workarounds or is it a browser implementation we can do nothing about?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on Snow Leopard and it looks fine. My want to restart your computer maybe it is just slowing with some of the new hardware acceleration.

Comment: This is not the issue here. I think it is the browser implementation of fading in text from transparent to opaque which in some browsers looks really bad as the font-weight appears to change during the animation. In other browsers, text fading does as expected with no change in font weight as the text fades in.